# Who is God of sight?

Tags: gods

Vak Devi is the goddess of speech and talking.

Which God or goddess is of seeing or sight? How may I pray to him? If a blind person prays to him, will he be able to see?

Comment: I think it's Sun.

Comment: You may also refer to Ashwin devatas; see Mahabharata aadi parva/Paushya parva chapter 4, where Dhaumya asks upamanyu to worship then for eye sight.

Answer (score 1):

The question raises complicated issues and I can give only a speculative answer.

I will give the Advaita Vedanta perspective. It is not the eye that sees but the mind. A blind person will need to pray to a god of the brain to see.

> True, Acarya Sankara, Suresvara and others acknowledge **the fact that
> the mind assumes the form of the external object from which it comes
> in contact, and modifies that form to suit its purposes.**

**Pancadasi IV.27**

> ...But it must be asserted **that external material objects are not
> known unless the mind comes in contact with them.**

**Commentary by Swami Tapasyananda**

**What does neuro-science say?**

**Neuro-science findings**

> One of the most fascinating recent developments in neuro-science
> concerns the functioning of our visual system. How do we see? How do
> we know that we have in front of us is a book or a cat.
>
> It would seem natural to think that receptors detect the light that
> reaches the retinas of our eyes and transform it into signals that
> race to the interior of the brain, where groups of neurons elaborate
> the information in ever more complex ways, until they elaborate the
> information in ever more complex ways, until they interpret it and
> identify it and identify the objects in question. Neurons recognize
> lines that separate colors, other neurons recognize shapes drawn by
> these lines, others again check these shapes against data stored in
> our memory…. Others still strive at the recognition: it’s a cat.
>
> **It turns out, however, that brain does not work like this at all. It
> functions, in fact, in an opposite way. The majority of the signals do
> not travel from the eyes to the brain; they go the other way, from the
> brain to the eyes.
>
> What happens is that the brain expects to see
> something, on the basis of what it knows and has previously occurred.**
> The brain elaborates an image of what it predicts the eyes should see.
> This information is conveyed from the brain to the eyes, through
> intermediate stages. If a discrepancy  is revealed between what the
> brain expects and the light arriving into the eyes, only then do the
> neural circuits send signals towards the brain. So images from around
> us do not travel from the eyes to the brain – only news of
> discrepancies regarding what the brain expects to do.

**Helgoland, But is it really possible? By Carlo Rovelli**

**General Discussion**

Rovelli being a materialist says that the brain expects to see something based on what it knows and what has previously occurred and it informs the eye. A little thought will tell you that Rovelli can't be right. How does a person see an object which has not been seen before by anyone? Surely brain can't predict in such a situation. Rovelli considers the mind to be the same as brain and thus is forced to his position.

Advaita Vedanta is clear that the mind comes out of the body and takes an imprint of the object through contact. Then it informs the brain. This is how the brain comes to know. Then the brain informs the eyes that there is an object out there. I don't know if there is a God of sight. What I can say is that a blind person will need a deity of the brain (if there is any such deity) to see.

Answer (score 1):

Lord Surya (Sun) is the Lord of the Vision.

**Aitareya Upanishad.:**

> *I:i:4.:-> He (Self/Atman) did penance with the resolution (of creation). From that austerity, an egg like mouth (face) was born. From the mouth (after parting/cracking) emerged speech (vāk); from speech came Fire. The nostrils parted; from the nostrils came out the sense of smell; from the sense of smell came Vayu (Air). **The two eyes parted; from the eyes emerged the sense of sight; from the sense of sight came the Sun.** The two ears parted; from the ears came the sense of hearing; from the sense of hearing came the Directions. The skin emerged; from the skin came out hair (i.e. the sense of touch associated with hair); from the sense of touch came the Herbs and Trees. The heart took shape; from the heart issued the internal organ (mind/manas); from the internal organ (manas) came the Moon. The navel parted; from the navel came out the organ of ejection; from the organ of ejection issued Death. The seat of the procreative organ parted; from that came the procreative organ; from the procreative organ came out Water.*

> *I-ii-3: For them He brought a man. They said "This one is well formed; man indeed is a creation of God Himself". To them He said, **"Enter into your respective abodes".***

> *I-ii-4: Fire entered into the mouth taking the form of the organ of speech; Air entered into the nostrils assuming the form of the sense of smell; **the Sun entered into the eyes as the sense of sight;** the Directions entered into the ears by becoming the sense of hearing; the Herbs and Trees entered into the skin in the form of hair (i.e. the sense of touch); the Moon entered into the heart in the shape of the mind; Death entered into the navel in the form of Apana (i.e. the vital energy that presses down); Water entered into the limb of generation in the form of semen (i.e. the organ of procreation).*

As Vision/Sight is also compared with knowledge. In our body Sun represents Buddhi or Intellect.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

*For any sensory organ such as an eye to function, it requires an anugraha of the Devata ( the presiding deity of the indriya) , which otherwise would be defunct due to that Devatas nigraha*

> Presiding deities avail themselves of the various sensory organs to hinder or to help one's progress. All that depends upon the nature of one's past actions.
>
> *svsss 420 , Translation Swami Tatvananda*

> The presiding deity of the eye—lit. the being associated with the eye—who is a part of the sun, being directed by the experiencer's past work, goes on helping the functions of the eye as long as he lives, but he ceases to help the eye and is merged in his own self, the sun, when the man is about to die. This has been stated in the passage, ‘When the vocal organ of the £ead man has been merged in fire, the vital force in Vayu, the eye in the sun,’ etc.
> Brihadaranyak upanishad(III. ii. 13). ,[4.4.2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc122058.html)

By listening to the recital of [Chaakshushopanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/chakshu.pdf), one may seek cure for eye ailments.

> This upanishad belongs to the Krishna Yajur veda recension,. Chakshus
> indicates eyes. Hence, naturally, this upanishad contains the hymns competent enough to remove the diseases affecting our eyes. There are two other upanishads, viz,
> Suryopanishad and Akshyopanishad, which are in praise of Sun the presiding deity of light & hence of the eyes.
> But, Chaakshushopanishad is mainly said to have the power to cure all the eye-ailments. The significance of this
> upanishad has been explained in the opening verses of
> mantra.
>
> *Dr T. Narayanan Kutti, S. Chakrapani*

*Meaning of chaakshushopanishad mantra*

> O! Lord Surya! please protect me and remove my eye-ailments immediately Let me able to see the divine
> luminous light enmanating from you (which is spiritual and
> gold). May the auspiciousness
> also glittering intto the eyes as gold).
> be showered upon me, that I don t suffer from blindness.
> May all the wrong deeds that I might have been committed
> in my previous births resulting in the impediment of vision
> pray to you. Kindly shower Thy
> be uprooted, for which I pray
> grace for the welfare of all.
>
> *Dr T. Narayanan Kutti, S. Chakrapani*